# Silverlight to HTML5 Azure VIP Swap

Tags: azure, deployment

I have a Silverlight App that is deployed to foo.cloudapp.net prod environment with cloud service named Foo.

Now I have created a HTML5 version of that app and would like to replace the Silverlight version.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Here is what I am thinking:

- Deploy HTML5 version Stating of Foo cloud service.
- Test the app completely over there
- Finally, swap the VIP between Stage and Prod.
- Delete the stage copy

Does this sound right?

When I do this, what happens to the previous SilverLight version on Prod? Is there anyway to revert back to Silverlight app if I have to?

Any comments, suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is probably the best way to do the upgrade.  Your older Silverlight version will switch to the staging slot and your new HTML5 version will switch to the production slot.  If you want to revert back you simply do another VIP swap.

Comment: is right, VIP SWAP just switch staging / prod versions. So, when you swap html5 do production, your silverlight will be in staging. If something goes wrong, just swap again